# Close ProgressCircle after most of the page is loaded in WebView

Tags: android, webview

So i'm loading a WebView and using a progressCircle to track the same. However, the progress circle doesn't close well until after all images in the WebView have been loaded. I want it to close right after the page loads, irrespective oh how many images have loaded. As of now, my code is:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            private ProgressDialog progressCircle;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progressCircle == null) {
                    progressCircle = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext(), R.style.WebViewLoadingCircle);
                    progressCircle.setCancelable(true);
                    progressCircle.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
                    try {
                        progressCircle.show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while showing progress circle", e);
                    }
                }

                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressCircle.dismiss();
                    progressCircle = null;
                }
            }
        });
```

How can i dismiss the progressCircle as soon as the webpage has loaded? (i've tried a lot of things, including playing with progress variable, but none of it has helped). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
                if (progressCircle != null) {
                    progressCircle.dismiss();
                    progressCircle = null;
                 }
     }
});
```

This full code for you task:

```
    boolean loadingFinished = true;
    boolean redirect = false;

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
           if (!loadingFinished) {
              redirect = true;
           }

       loadingFinished = false;
       webView.loadUrl(urlNewString);
       return true;
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
            loadingFinished = false;
            //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE
if (progressCircle == null) {
                    progressCircle = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext(), R.style.WebViewLoadingCircle);
                    progressCircle.setCancelable(true);
                    progressCircle.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
                    try {
                        progressCircle.show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while showing progress circle", e);
                    }
                }  
        }

       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                      if (progressCircle != null) {
                        progressCircle.dismiss();
                        progressCircle = null;
                     }

        }
    });
```

Enjoy it!

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but i'm having an issue. This works but not for the first time i open the app. The first time the webview opens after opening the app, it still waits for everything to load, while consecutive openings of the webview (without closing the app), leads to the required result. Any workaround?